# How to temporarily light up a div

Tags: jquery

does anyone have a clue how to light up a div, or change it's background color after sliding to it like shown in the fiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/ChhKF/

Something like this seems to be the only thing that I can find..

```
$(this.hash).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have jQuery included, see adjusted: http://jsfiddle.net/ChhKF/2/

Comment: Thanks for the update. But the background color was the thing I found that worked. I'm looking for something to temporarily change backgroundcolor and then change it back or something.

Comment: Well, there's many different ways, that being one of them.. :| (but if that works, doesn't that, answer your question?) Although, personally I'd say it's best managing background colors by the management of classes: `.addClass('redbackground');`, then afterwards, `.removeClass( 'redbackground' )`

Comment: Because I also want it to change back. like a short highlight so the user sees what div he's being reffered to.

Comment: If you include the jQuery UI, you can do it with `.switchClass` fairly quickly: http://jsfiddle.net/6nS5U/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I've decided to use the highlight effect from jquery ui.

```
$(this.hash).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done before:

1) Have a child element, with position: absolute; width and height set to 100%.

2) Give that child a border-shadow, looking like the highlight you want and, here is the important part, opacity: 0;

3) Animate the opacity to 1 with jQuery, then back to 0 after the animation is done.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to temporarily change the background color and then switch it back, like a short highlight. And i'd prefer it to not use child elements.